# easy way to edit all the titles of the pages on my site without having to edit each page's title tags individually?

Tags: php, css, header, tags, title

I'm working on my website made from php, and my programmer put the following code on the top of most pages: `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>`

Now in the header.php file, the title is Untitled Document. Is there an easy way for me to just edit the header.php file and have it change all the title tags of the pages that use the above function to call it?

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to give more information - what's in header.php and how it is used on the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In header.php there will be a variable such as $title. On your pages, if you are declaring the title on each page, then use $title instead of typing the title. Be sure that the include('header.php'); comes before your use of the $title variable.

Comment: Hey thanks dude this makes sense. I have about 20 pages that call the header.php file. Each one needs different title tags. I don't have to make different variables right? Could I just put code in the header that writes the title in for a page on the site?

Comment: ouch..you only want to do this on pages that will all have the SAME title. Only makes sense to put them in the header.php file and use a variable if you will have multiple pages that will have the same title. EDTI: Unless you want to have one single file to change titles in, and assign each title a different variable. Then, I guess it could be a time-saver.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the header.php, all pages that call in the include will show your changes.